psycopg2 ошибка "ссылки между базами нереализованы" при запросе к базе с названием в кавычках
Запрос ниже прекрасно выполняется в dBeaver:
SELECT DISTINCT ta.docdb_family_id FROM "FBGISPA".patstat.tls201_appln ta LIMIT 20

При отправке этого запроса через psycopg2 получаю ошибку:

ОШИБКА:  ссылки между базами не реализованы: "FBGISPA.patstat.tls201_appln"
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT(docdb_family_id) FROM "FBGISPA".patstat.tls2...

Пробовал по-разному.
Так:
query = 'SELECT DISTINCT docdb_family_id FROM "FBGISPA".patstat.tls201_appln LIMIT 20'

Так:
query = sql.SQL('SELECT DISTINCT(docdb_family_id) FROM {0}.patstat.tls201_appln LIMIT 20').format(sql.Identifier('FBGISPA'))

Результат не меняется.
Как реализовать такой запрос в psycopg2?
Заранее спасибо!
